# How to view a particular google drive file id using filename?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, coding-style

please, How to view a particular google drive file id using filename inside the developers google drive (Not users google drive account) in android... I hope this is possible. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get a file's `DRIVE_FILE_ID`, you need to be authorized and make a call to `files.get` or `files.list` atleast. However, you can only access your own files not someone else's. [Authentication and Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) exist for a reason.